# Minimize WMP12 to notification area in Win7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, notification-area

I want to minimize Windows Media Player to the notification area in Windows 7 (64-bit) as is possible with alternate media players such as VLC. Is there an easy way to get this done?

**P.S.:** I'm not trying to get the player to appear as a toolbar in my taskbar.

Comment: Windows Media Player has never minimized to the notification area only the taskbar. If you want the functionality out of your video player a different application is advised.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm aware that there is no built in functionality to do so. I still need WMP as my headset controls don't seem to work with other players when minimized.

Comment: WMP does not support being minimized into the notification area. It does not have a notification area icon. That support has to be specifically added into a program by the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

3 years later this question...

I was just searching for the same topic, and I have coincidentally found a program named [Mooo0 Windows Menu Plus](http://www.moo0.com/?top=http://www.moo0.com/software/WindowMenuPlus/)
that has an option named “Iconize to tray” that hides most of the programs, including WMP, to the tray.

I hope it helps others, because there are no search results that appear to be talking about that option in the “Mooo0” program.

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Media Bonus Pack for XP](http://download.microsoft.com/download/winmediaplayer/install/xp/wxp/en-us/wmbonusxp.exe) includes a powertoy for controlling WMP through the system tray. Not sure if this will still work on Windows 7 but chances are it will.

It also doesn't offer a perfect 'minimize to tray' - instead, you need to right-click the icon and select `Hide Media Player`.